# Routes and query strings magic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So, I recently saw this code:

```
<%= link_to "Index", plays_path(id: 1) %>
```

1) I did not know that the index path or the `plays_path` took arguments. The URL doesn't have any named parameters and so I didn't think you could.

2) I read about query strings but the docs aren't great.
[ActionView UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

There is no usage of the word query strings. How can you just pass any hash to a path in rails and have the params be available in the following controller? What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly correct.  Any parameters you pass in to URL / path helpers (which are not part of a named route, such as `:id`) will be available as parameters within your controller.

The [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) talks a bit about parameters and is always a good resource for how to best utilize additional parameters passed through a `_url` or `_path` helper.

Answer (score 0):

All of the path helpers take a hash of arguments on the end. They're passed as extra parameters in the query string. For instance: `plays_path(id: 1)` will (likely) generate `/plays?id=1`. You can append a whole mess of them on the end as in `user_path(user, active_user: 5, secure: 1, other_thing: 'happy')` where `user` is an instance of `User` with id `30`, would generate `/user/30?active_user=5&secure=1&other_thing=happy`. Most of the time these are GET parameters.